# Scifi story from my childhood about green worms/cocoons and a mechanical snake

Tags: story-identification, movie

All I remember is these weird cocoons like caterpillars of green color and a mechanical grey snake swooshing around a space station choking people. I have no idea if it was a movie or a TV series but i remember it vividly and cannot find it anywhere. If someone has any idea please help. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Feel free to take the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand our site better. You can also visit this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/) and add more details to your question so it's easier for others to find an answer for you.

Comment: So you read it last year, or five years ago, or ten years ago?

Comment: Is this something you watched or something you read? You refer to it both ways.

Comment: It's either a movie or a show. I watched it as a kid around 30y ago.

Comment: Could you be confounding two episodes of Dr Who, [The Green Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Green_Death) (1972/1973) and [Revenge of the Cybermen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revenge_of_the_Cybermen)(1975)?

Comment: Jan Heric - next time be sure to properly use words.  "Story" refers to something printed, so don't use it to describe movies or TV shows.

Answer (score 8):

There's at least some similarity to the original run Doctor Who story, "The Ark in Space". It takes place on a space station named Nerva. This station was converted to cryogenically freeze a number of people while the Earth underwent a crisis. While everyone was frozen an alien (the Wyrrn, or something like that) broke in and died, leaving behind some kind of green goo that could transform other species into Wyrrn. No mechanical snake that I can recall, but early on there is someone who comes to the ship and is placed in cryo-sleep (for a very short period, a matter of hours) because the ship isn't generating oxygen yet (as best I recall).

The Green goo spreads over the one person converted to a Wyrrn, so some strong memories of green are fulfilled.

Note: another Doctor Who story from the same season took place on the same space station earlier in time, and that involved mechanical critters called cybermats - those could have been recalled as snakes, and I think at least one jumped on someone's neck and bit them, injecting some sort of poison. That story is "The Revenge of the Cybermen".

In the mid-80s, public broadcasting stations would regular show entire stories (usually 4-6 episodes of the TV show) on the weekends; under those conditions, the two stories would have been shown 2-3 weeks apart, close enough to conflate since the lead characters were the same (The fourth Doctor (curly brown hair and a very long scarf), Sarah Jane Smith, and Harry Sullivan (a Navy doctor)).

Comment: I too think there is a strong possibility that Jan Heric's memory is combining "The Ark in Space" and  "Revenge of the Cybermen".

Answer (score 2):

I think the movie that you're thinking of is *[Doc Savage, The Man Of Bronze (1975)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072886/)*. I myself was looking around trying to find out what this weird movie was that I saw when I was a kid.  This movie deals with a green death, weird badly animated flying green worms.

> Doc and the Amazing Five battle Captain Seas and "the green death" for control of a fabulous resource.
>   <sub>[From IMBD](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072886/)</sub>

**Trailer**